# how to get text of <p> without <br/> using lxml in python?

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="body">
    <p>this is the<br />
    text that i want to<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    get from html file<br />
    .<br />
    .</p>
    <div class="sender">someone</div>
</div>
```

I only want the text in `<p>` tag without `<br/>` tags inside it. Also I need the periods between lines too!
I'm using lxml, And my code looks like this:
`jokes = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'body')]/p/text()")`
It returns every line into the list as ONE item. But I need all `<p>` tag's text as one item in the list.
Is there any way to add the whole p tag without br tags into the list as one item?

Something like this:

```
this is the
text that i want to
.
.
get from html file
.
.
```

When I save the list into a file by this code:

```
with open('c:\\f.txt','w') as f:
for l in jokes:
    f.write(l+'**************')
```

This is what I see in the file:

```
this is the************
    text that i want to************
    .************
    .************
    get from html file************
    .************
    .************
```

Comment: so you are getting `"this is the<br />text that i want to<br />.<br />"` etcetera as a string as your output?

Comment: No, When i save items of the list in a file, There is no br tags. But every line of text is added in the list, not the whole of p tag. I want the whole p tag to be added as one item in the list.

Comment: plz print exactly what you are getting as an output.

Comment: Using your code, I get a list containing all of the text strings, but no `br` tags, i.e. `['this is the', '\n    text that i want to', '\n    .', '\n    .', '\n    get from html file', '\n    .', '\n    .']`.

Comment: I know. But I want all the text as one item in the list: ['this is the text that i want to \n . \n . \n get from html file \n . \n .']

Comment: then `all_one_item = [''.join(your_list_of_stuff)]` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe overkill depending on the scope of your scraping but try out [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
HTML = """"<div class="body">
    <p>this is the<br />
    text that i want to<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    get from html file<br />
    .<br />
    .</p>
    <div class="sender">someone</div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML)
print soup.p.get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pete's right, Beautiful Soup is going to help here. For what it's worth, you can also strip tags with the following function:

```
def stripTags(in_text):
            # convert in_text to a mutable object (e.g. list)
            s_list = list(in_text)
            i,j = 0,0
            while i < len(s_list):
                    # iterate until a left-angle bracket is found
                    if s_list[i] == '<':
                            while s_list[i] != '>':
                                    # pop everything from the the left-angle bracket until the right-angle bracket
                                    s_list.pop(i)   
                            # pops the right-angle bracket, too
                            s_list.pop(i)
                    else:
                            i=i+1       
            # convert the list back into text
            join_char=''
            return join_char.join(s_list)
```